# InnoSetup: insert an image with a link

Tags: inno-setup

Good afternoon, I'm working on a section of the installer where I want to insert an image with a link in wpInstalling section but I don't manage to do it, I know how to insert text but I don't know how to do what I said before. I hope you can help me.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you v20100v for your reply, but I found a simple way to do it. Here I leave the code just in case someone needs it.

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Files]
Source: "Logo.bmp"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]
procedure MyImageClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
  ShellExec('open', 'http://www.google.es', '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
end;

procedure CreateMyImage();
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFile('Logo.bmp');
  with TBitmapImage.Create(WizardForm) do
  begin
    Parent := WizardForm.InstallingPage;
    Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Logo.bmp'));
    AutoSize := True;
    Left := 0;
    Top := WizardForm.InstallingPage.Top + WizardForm.InstallingPage.Height - Height - 8;
    Cursor := crHand;
    OnClick := @MyImageClick;
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  CreateMyImage();
end;
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for this, & finally got this as my solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can find more information in this project (made by a japanese dvp). He creates a web control in InnoSetup.

- Blog here :  [Innosetup webctrl v2.1](http://restools.hanzify.org/article.asp?id=90)
- Download here : [inno_webctrl_v2.1.zip](http://restools.hanzify.org/inno/webctrl/inno_webctrl_v2.1.zip)